# Intel Media Server Studio 2017 R3が最小インストールのCentOS7.3にインストールできない

Tags: centos

Intel Media Server Studio 2017 R3をCentOS7.3にインストールしようとしていますが、最初のところでつまずいています。
環境は以下の通りです。

```
# more /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

の最小インストール(minimum install)

```
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6770HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz

# lspci -nn -s 0:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Iris Pro Graphics 580 [8086:193b] (rev 09)

# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016
```

インストール手順ですが、

mirrorlistにコメントアウトして、baseurlのコメントアウトを削除しました。
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repoを

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&rep
o=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

tar -xzf MediaServerStudioEssentials2017R3.tar.gz
cd MediaServerStudioEssentials2017R3
tar -xzf SDK2017Production16.5.2.tar.gz
cd SDK2017Production16.5.2/CentOS
tar -xzf install_scripts_centos_16.5.2-64009.tar.gz
su
./install_sdk_CentOS.sh
・・・
If no response in 120 seconds option 1 will be default [1]で「1」を選択
・・・
エラー: パッケージ: elfutils-devel-0.166-2.el7.x86_64 (mss_vault_base)
             要求: elfutils-libs(x86-64) = 0.166-2.el7
            インストール: elfutils-libs-0.168-8.el7.x86_64 (@base/7)
                elfutils-libs(x86-64) = 0.168-8.el7
            利用可能: elfutils-libs-0.166-2.el7.x86_64 (mss_vault_base)
                elfutils-libs(x86-64) = 0.166-2.el7
エラー: パッケージ: elfutils-libelf-devel-0.166-2.el7.x86_64 (mss_vault_base)
             要求: elfutils-libelf(x86-64) = 0.166-2.el7
            インストール: elfutils-libelf-0.168-8.el7.x86_64 (@base/7)
                elfutils-libelf(x86-64) = 0.168-8.el7
            利用可能: elfutils-libelf-0.166-2.el7.x86_64 (mss_vault_base)
                elfutils-libelf(x86-64) = 0.166-2.el7
エラー: パッケージ: audit-libs-devel-2.6.5-3.el7_3.1.x86_64 (mss_vault_updates)
             要求: audit-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.5-3.el7_3.1
            インストール: audit-libs-2.7.6-3.el7.x86_64 (@base/7)
                audit-libs(x86-64) = 2.7.6-3.el7
            利用可能: audit-libs-2.6.5-3.el7.x86_64 (mss_vault_base)
                audit-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.5-3.el7
            利用可能: audit-libs-2.6.5-3.el7_3.1.x86_64 (mss_vault_updates)
                audit-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.5-3.el7_3.1

 問題を回避するために --skip-broken を用いることができます。
 これらを試行できます: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
yum install failed!
```

のようにインストールに失敗します。

またinstall_sdk_CentOS.shを書き換えましたので添付します。

```
# more install_sdk_CentOS.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

#/******************************************************************************
***
#
#INTEL CORPORATION PROPRIETARY INFORMATION
#This software is supplied under the terms of a license agreement or nondisclosu
re
#agreement with Intel Corporation and may not be copied or disclosed except in
#accordance with the terms of that agreement
#Copyright(c) 2011-2017 Intel Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
#
#*******************************************************************************
***/

BUILD_ID=64009
MILESTONE_VER=16.5.2
LIBDRM_VER=2.4.67
LIBVA_VER=1.67.0.pre1

OS_VERSION_LIMIT="7.3.1611"
YUM_REPO_LIMIT="--releasever=$OS_VERSION_LIMIT"
YUM_REPO_FORCE="--releasever=7"

MSS_YUMREPO_FILE=/etc/yum.repos.d/MSS-Install.repo

function check_yum_repo() {
check_result=$(mktemp) || {
    echo "Unknow error!"
    exit 1
}
echo "Checking yum by paramters \"$@\"..."

yum "$@" check-update kernel 2> $check_result
if grep -e "Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo" -we "Errno" $check_result ; th
en
    rm -f $check_result
    echo "Checking yum by paramters \"$@\"...Failed!"
    #found error, return a NON-zero value
    return 1
else
    rm -f $check_result
    echo "Checking yum by paramters \"$@\"...Succeeded!"
    #check pass, 0 means successful
    return 0
fi
}

function create_mss_install_repo() {
echo "[mss_base]"
 >  $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "name=CentOS-mss_base - Base"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$OS_VERSION_LIMIT/os/x86_64/"
>> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "gpgcheck=1"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "enabled=0"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo ""
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "[mss_updates]"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "name=CentOS-mss_updates - Updates"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$OS_VERSION_LIMIT/updates/x86_64/"
>> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "gpgcheck=1"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "enabled=0"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo ""
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "[mss_vault_base]"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "name=CentOS-mss_vault_base - Base"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$OS_VERSION_LIMIT/os/x86_64/"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "gpgcheck=1"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "enabled=0"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo ""
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "[mss_vault_updates]"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "name=CentOS-mss_vault_updates - Updates"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/$OS_VERSION_LIMIT/updates/x86_64/"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "gpgcheck=1"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
echo "enabled=0"
 >> $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
}

function install_prerequisites() {
# whether $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE is used, and whether yum install succeeds, we should
 ensure remove
# $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE always after run this function
echo "Installing prerequisiters with yum parameters \"$@\"..."
yum -y -t "$@" groupinstall "Development Tools" || {
    rm -f $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
    echo "yum groupinstall failed!"
    exit 2
}
yum -y -t "$@" install kernel-headers kernel-devel bc wget bison ncurses-devel h
maccalc zlib-devel binutils-devel elfutils-libelf-devel rpm-build redhat-rpm-con
fig asciidoc hmaccalc perl-ExtUtils-Embed pesign xmlto audit-libs-devel binutils
-devel elfutils-devel elfutils-libelf-devel newt-devel numactl-devel pciutils-de
vel python-devel zlib-devel || {
    rm -f $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
    echo "yum install failed!"
    exit 3
}
echo "Installing prerequisiters with yum parameters \"$@\"...Succeeded!"
rm -f $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
}

function install_mss_packages() {
#install Media Server Studio packages
echo "Installing user-space library rpms..."
rpm -Uvh \
libdrm-$LIBDRM_VER-$BUILD_ID.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
libdrm-devel-$LIBDRM_VER-$BUILD_ID.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
drm-utils-$LIBDRM_VER-$BUILD_ID.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
libva-$LIBVA_VER-$BUILD_ID.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
libva-devel-$LIBVA_VER-$BUILD_ID.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
libva-utils-$LIBVA_VER-$BUILD_ID.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
intel-linux-media-$MILESTONE_VER-$BUILD_ID.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
intel-linux-media-devel-$MILESTONE_VER-$BUILD_ID.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
intel-opencl-*.x86_64.rpm || {
    echo "Installing user-space library rpms...Failed!"
    exit 4
}

#remove all other kmod-ukmd installation
for installed_kmod in `rpm -qa | grep kmod-ukmd`
do
    echo "Removing previous version $installed_kmod..."
    rpm -e $installed_kmod || {
        echo "Removing previous version $installed_kmod...Failed!"
        exit 5
    }
done

#install kmod-ukmd
echo "Installing kmod-ukmd-$MILESTONE_VER-$BUILD_ID..."
rpm -ivh kmod-ukmd-$MILESTONE_VER-$BUILD_ID.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm || {
    echo "Installing kmod-ukmd-$MILESTONE_VER-$BUILD_ID...Failed!"
    exit 6
}

echo ""
echo "Installation done. Please reboot."
echo ""
}


# Check whether --releasever=7.3.1611 work, if so, could start installation dire
ctly.
# Besides --releasever=7.3.1611 just working naturely (if the yum repos have alr
eady modified in any proper way),
# there is also a possibility that this is the second run of this script, and du
ring the first run, option 2 (as below)
# was choosen and the yum repos have modified according to the prompts.
yum_commands=($YUM_REPO_LIMIT)
if check_yum_repo "${yum_commands[@]}"; then
   install_prerequisites "${yum_commands[@]}"
   install_mss_packages
   # all installation succeed
   exit 0
fi

# "--releasever=" yum option does not work
clear
echo "This Version of MediaServerStudio has been validated against CentOS $OS_VE
RSION_LIMIT."
echo "To install MediaServerStudio there is a requirement to install packages us
ing yum package manager."
echo "yum package manager automatically installs from latest CentOS released ver
sion repository."
echo "If CentOS latest release version is newer than $OS_VERSION_LIMIT, yum will
 default to install packages from this repository."
echo "This could lead to packages been installed that could conflict with this v
ersion of MediaServerStudio and cause installation to fail."
echo "It is ultimate responsibility of user to manage yum repositories to ensure
 that packages installed during installation of MediaServerStudio using yum pack
age manger are installed from correct repository."
echo "For more information on CentOS version please see: \"https://wiki.centos.o
rg/FAQ/General#head-dcca41e9a3d5ac4c6d900a991990fd11930867d6\""
echo ""
echo ""
echo "User has 3 options to proceed with installation:"
echo "1: (default) Installation Script will automatically attempt to enable corr
ect repositories to install from."
echo "2: User can manually edit yum repository files to ensure yum installs from
 correct repository, i.e. \"$YUM_REPO_LIMIT\" is workable."
echo "   If this option is chosen installation will abort then user need to fix
yum repository files and run this script again."
echo "3: Force installation from default yum repository, i.e. using \"$YUM_REPO_
FORCE\" yum option (ONLY for advanced users who clearly know what will happen)"
echo ""

read -t 120 -p "If no response in 120 seconds option 1 will be default [1]" inpu
t
if [ -z "$input" ]; then
   input=1
fi

if [ "$input" == "1" ]; then
    clear
    create_mss_install_repo
    yum_commands=(--disablerepo "*" --enablerepo "mss_base" --enablerepo "mss_up
dates" $YUM_REPO_LIMIT)
    if check_yum_repo "${yum_commands[@]}"; then
        install_prerequisites "${yum_commands[@]}"
        install_mss_packages
        # all installation succeed
        exit 0
    fi
    # mirror repo cannot work, try vault repo
    yum_commands=(--disablerepo "*" --enablerepo "mss_vault_base" --enablerepo "
mss_vault_updates" $YUM_REPO_LIMIT)
    if check_yum_repo "${yum_commands[@]}"; then
        install_prerequisites "${yum_commands[@]}"
        install_mss_packages
        # all installation succeed
        exit 0
    fi
    # neither mirror nor vault repo can work
    echo ""
    echo "Installation has failed as Automatic installation could not successful
ly connect to correct yum repositories."
    echo "Please consider to use option 2 or 3 when re-run this script."
    echo "Installation Aborted!"
    # to ensure $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE is removed
    rm -f $MSS_YUMREPO_FILE
    exit 7
elif [ "$input" == "2" ]; then
    echo ""
    echo "   Here is an example how to fix yum repository file but just for info
rmation -"
    echo "   Edit /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, comment out the mirrorlist
lines, uncomment and edit the baseurl lines for each entry to point to correct U
RL -"
    echo "   (a)"
    echo "   ===================================================================
================================="
    echo "   #mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=\$releasever&arch
=\$basearch&repo=os&infra=\$infra"
    echo "   baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/\$releasever/os/\$basearch/
"
    echo "   ===================================================================
================================="
    echo "   OR (b)"
    echo "   ===================================================================
================================="
    echo "   #mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=\$releasever&arch
=\$basearch&repo=os&infra=\$infra"
    echo "   baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/\$releasever/os/\$basearch/"
    echo "   ===================================================================
================================="
    echo "   The reason of (b) is centos will move from mirror to vault for old
versions then (a) won't work any longer."
    echo "   One example for old CentOS7.2 is"
    echo "       http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/readme"
    echo "   It is expected the same deprecation of mirror will happen one day f
or CentOS7.3, too."
    echo ""
    echo "Please finish the modification and re-run the script to install."
    echo ""
elif [ "$input" == "3" ]; then
    yum_commands=($YUM_REPO_FORCE)
    install_prerequisites "${yum_commands[@]}"
    install_mss_packages
    # all installation succeed
    exit 0
else
    echo "Invid input! Please rerun the script and choose one valid option."
    echo "Installation aborted!"
fi
```

また、レポジトリがすでに消えてしまっているということで、/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repoを以下のように書き換えました。一応、baseurlにあるURLの存在確認はしました。

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&rep
o=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&rep
o=updates&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&rep
o=extras&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&rep
o=centosplus&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

これで、

```
# sudo yum clean all
# sudo yum update
```

をしました。

ここまでやってのレポジトリの一覧ですが、

```
リポジトリー ID                   リポジトリー名                     状態
C7.0.1406-base/x86_64             CentOS-7.0.1406 - Base             無効
C7.0.1406-centosplus/x86_64       CentOS-7.0.1406 - CentOSPlus       無効
C7.0.1406-extras/x86_64           CentOS-7.0.1406 - Extras           無効
C7.0.1406-fasttrack/x86_64        CentOS-7.0.1406 - CentOSPlus       無効
C7.0.1406-updates/x86_64          CentOS-7.0.1406 - Updates          無効
C7.1.1503-base/x86_64             CentOS-7.1.1503 - Base             無効
C7.1.1503-centosplus/x86_64       CentOS-7.1.1503 - CentOSPlus       無効
C7.1.1503-extras/x86_64           CentOS-7.1.1503 - Extras           無効
C7.1.1503-fasttrack/x86_64        CentOS-7.1.1503 - CentOSPlus       無効
C7.1.1503-updates/x86_64          CentOS-7.1.1503 - Updates          無効
C7.2.1511-base/x86_64             CentOS-7.2.1511 - Base             無効
C7.2.1511-centosplus/x86_64       CentOS-7.2.1511 - CentOSPlus       無効
C7.2.1511-extras/x86_64           CentOS-7.2.1511 - Extras           無効
C7.2.1511-fasttrack/x86_64        CentOS-7.2.1511 - CentOSPlus       無効
C7.2.1511-updates/x86_64          CentOS-7.2.1511 - Updates          無効
base/x86_64                       CentOS-7 - Base                    有効: 9,363
base-debuginfo/x86_64             CentOS-7 - Debuginfo               無効
base-source/7                     CentOS-7 - Base Sources            無効
c7-media                          CentOS-7 - Media                   無効
centosplus/x86_64                 CentOS-7 - Plus                    無効
centosplus-source/7               CentOS-7 - Plus Sources            無効
cr/7/x86_64                       CentOS-7 - cr                      無効
docker-ce-edge/x86_64             Docker CE Edge - x86_64            有効:    14
docker-ce-edge-debuginfo/x86_64   Docker CE Edge - Debuginfo x86_64  無効
docker-ce-edge-source             Docker CE Edge - Sources           無効
docker-ce-stable/x86_64           Docker CE Stable - x86_64          有効:    12
docker-ce-stable-debuginfo/x86_64 Docker CE Stable - Debuginfo x86_6 無効
docker-ce-stable-source           Docker CE Stable - Sources         無効
docker-ce-test/x86_64             Docker CE Test - x86_64            無効
docker-ce-test-debuginfo/x86_64   Docker CE Test - Debuginfo x86_64  無効
docker-ce-test-source             Docker CE Test - Sources           無効
extras/x86_64                     CentOS-7 - Extras                  有効:   451
extras-source/7                   CentOS-7 - Extras Sources          無効
fasttrack/7/x86_64                CentOS-7 - fasttrack               無効
updates/x86_64                    CentOS-7 - Updates                 有効: 2,146
updates-source/7                  CentOS-7 - Updates Sources         無効
zabbix/x86_64                     Zabbix Official Repository - x86_6 有効:   222
zabbix-non-supported/x86_64       Zabbix Official Repository non-sup 有効:     4
repolist: 12,212
```

となっています。

何か手順が抜けているのか、間違っているのかわかりませんが、ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

利用されている7.3(1611)は既に古いバージョンになるので、ミラーサイトからは削除されているようです。
参照してるミラーサイトをチェックしてみると以下のファイルが置いてあります。

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/readme

> This directory (and version of CentOS) is deprecated.  For normal users, you should use /7/ and not /7.3.1611/ in your path. Please see this FAQ concerning the CentOS release scheme:
>
> https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General
>
> If you know what you are doing, and absolutely want to remain at the 7.3.1611 level, go to http://vault.centos.org/ for packages.
>
> Please keep in mind that 7.3.1611 no longer gets any updates, nor any security fix's.

本家のミラーサイトには常に最新版、現時点では7.4(1708)のみが置いてあり、**過去のバージョンが必要な場合には以下のアーカイブサイトを参照するように**、とのことです。

http://vault.centos.org/

ディレクトリ構造は同じはずなので、yumの設定ファイルでbaseurlのドメイン名の部分を書き換えてみてください。

---

必要なパッケージが足りていないようなので、インストールスクリプトを実行する前にエラーで表示されているパッケージをインストールしてみてください。

`$ sudo yum install audit-libs elfutils-libelf -y`

Comment: baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/os/$basearch/
のように書き換えましたが、
#  ./install_sdk_CentOS.sh
・・・ 
問題を回避するために --skip-broken を用いることができます。
 これらを試行できます: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
yum install failed!
のようなエラーになります。

Comment: 追伸ですが、install_sdk_CentOS.shの中のmirrorもvaultに書き換えました。

Comment: yumの設定ファイルを書き換えた後は念のため`yum clean all`を実行してみてください。また、`install_sdk_CentOS.sh`の中身も可能であれば質問文に追記してみてください。

Comment: yum clean allをsuで実行しましたが、状況変わらず。install_sdk_CentOS.shの中身も長文になってしまい恐縮ですが質問文に追記しました。

Comment: 小出しですみません、`yum clean all`のあとは`yum update`もですね。本文にも追記しましたので確認してみてください。

Comment: yum updateを行うと、http://vault.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Foundのようなエラーが出ました。vault.centos.orgのサイトでもファイルが削除されているのが原因でしょうか。

Comment: 正しくは`http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/`のはずです。ブラウザでドメイントップから辿れます。

Comment: /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repoをbaseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.3.1611/os/$basearch/にしました。一度、yum updateではエラーが出なくなりましたが、./install_sdk_CentOS.shでは質問と同じエラーが発生します。※コメントでhttpコロンスラッシュスラッシュが消えるようです。

Comment: sudo yum install audit-libs elfutils-libelf -yも実行しました。